# Adding extra queries to whereHas

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-nova

I am selecting all the broadcasts that belong to the same organization as the authenticated user, this works perfectly with `->whereHas()` but what if i wanted to add a filter to display only the `broadcasts` where `is_published` is `true`.

```
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    if (Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
        return $query;
    }else{
        return $query->whereHas('organizations', function($q){
            $q->where('organization_id', Auth::user()->organization_id);
        });
    }
}
```

models

```
public function organizations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Organization');
}

public function broadcasts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Broadcast');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a query scope to your `Broadcast` model which will query only `broadcasts` where `is_published` is `true` (This is good for future queries in your application where you need published broadcasts):

**Broadcast.php** (or model file)

```
public scopePublished($query)
{
    return $query->where('is_published', true);
}
```

Then in your code, and the `->published()` scope to your query:

```
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    if (Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
        return $query;
    } else {
        return $query->published()
            ->whereHas('organizations', function($q){
                $q->where('organization_id', Auth::user()->organization_id);
            });
    }
}
```